# SSRS Parameter not accepting multiple values

Tags: parameters, ssrs-2008, parameter-passing

I'm trying to create a parameter that will accept multiple values for the report. The report runs off a procedure and works if I only select one collection operation but when I try to select multiple, I get:

```
An error has occurred during report processing.
Query execution failed for dataset 'proc_Incentives'
Error converting data type nvarchar to int
```

In my procedure, I declared @CO_ID int as a variable.

In the WHERE clause, I set CO.CodeID in (@CO_ID).

Also, CO.CodeID is stored as an INT in the database.

In my SSRS report, I created a new dataset named 'prmCollectionOp' in which I wrote a simple query:

```
Select CodeID, Description from IDViewCollectionOp Order by Description;
```

Then I went created a new parameter named 'CO_ID' and made the data type Integer and checked "Allow Multiple Values".

Under Available Values, I chose Get values from a query, chose prmCollectionOp and placed CodeID in the value field and Description in the label field.

For Default Values, I also chose Get values from a query and picked dataset prmCollectionOp with Value Field of CodeID.

This all works with one single collection operation chosen, but not with multiple.

Any suggestions on what I might have missed to allow for multiple values to be selected in the parameter?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a tricky one: I am going to recommend several articles which explain how to do this.

One is from [Scott Murray](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2866/sql-server-reporting-services-using-multivalue-parameters/) and the other is from [Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) (Scott actually refers to Jeff's article in his).

For a stored proc you can do the following

Scott explains:

> First we are passing in the concatenated multi-value parameter as a single entity and we use a varchar parameter (which must be large enough to accept the maximum length of all the parameters which might be selected). Next using the splitter function, the values are parsed out and placed into a temporary table, #YEAR_LIST. Last, the year criteria is moved from being part of the where clause to being part of the joins.

There are other ways as well but this should solve the issue.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Bactos, I found the first one via Google and tried it, but didn't have much luck but I'll go back and try again.

Comment: I added an expression on the procedure dataset for the variable that should accept multiple values: =Join(Parameters!CO_ID.Value,",") but that  doesn't work... Ugh.

Comment: Have you tried to use a Split Function ? You can use this with a recursive CTE: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/19/how-to-split-a-string-by-delimited-char-in-sql-server/ and http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/666620/T-SQL-Most-Practical-Split-Function Because when you are using a stored procedure and passing a parameter into that procedure it is being passed in as 1 value (no matter how many values you think you have) you have to split them up.

Comment: OK. I've never used this so I'll have to read these articles and see if I can figure out how to call this function.  Do you call it within the procedure that gathers the data for the report?

Comment: You would call it from within the sproc you are using.

Comment: As an aside, if I were to get my data from a view instead of a procedure, do you know if it would still require a split function or would SSRS be able to separate the values?

Comment: If you don't use the sproc and use text as your query type in ssrs, you would not need to use a split function.

Answer (score 0):

Just use join  multivalue parameters with comma delimiter ( Dataset->Paremeter->Expression)

In the storedprocedure , split input value by delimiter(,) . then process the value in query with cross apply

[image: Dataset properties]
[image: Parameter mapping expression]

Comment: Thanks Ezhil, would you be able to share with me how to do this: In the storedprocedure , split input value by delimiter(,) ?

Comment: Pass combined input by delimiter to  storeprocedure ( eg. usp_process(input varchar(max)) . Then develop split string table value return  function. After that join functon with cross apply
Go through this url how to create table value split string function
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/19/how-to-split-a-string-by-delimited-char-in-sql-server/

Query will be

select *
from 
table a cross apply splitstring(input,',')